# .NET6 and docker: Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I'm trying to containerize a .NET6 WebApi with a postgrescontainer. I have this Docker file to build the web api image:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MicroserviceTemplateDDD.csproj", "MicroserviceTemplateDDD/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MicroserviceTemplateDDD/MicroserviceTemplateDDD.csproj"
WORKDIR "/src/MicroserviceTemplateDDD"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "MicroserviceTemplateDDD.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MicroserviceTemplateDDD.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
WORKDIR /app/publish
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MicroserviceTemplateDDD.dll"]
```

This runs successfully. But when i run docker-compose up to start the postgre and webapi container i get this error:

```
microservicetemplateddd_service1 | Process terminated. Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system. Please install libicu using your package manager and try again. Alternatively you can set the configuration flag System.Globalization.Invariant to true if you want to run with no globalization support. Please see https://aka.ms/dotnet-missing-libicu for more information.
```

My docker compose:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    api:
        image:  microservicetemplateddd_service1
        container_name:  microservicetemplateddd_service1
        restart: always
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        environment:
            - ConnectionStrings:Context=Server=MicroserviceTemplateDDD_Service1_database;Database=Database;User Id=pa;Password=P4ssW0rd!;
            - DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false
        depends_on:
            - database
        networks:
            - network
        ports:
            - 8090:80
    database:
        image: postgres
        container_name: microservicetemplateddd_service1_database
        restart: always
        environment:
            - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=P4ssW0rd!
            - POSTGRES_USER=pa
        networks:
            - network
        ports:
            - 1433:1433
        volumes:
            - database:/var/opt/mssql

networks:
    network:
volumes:
    database:
```

I already tried to use other ms images like alpine and change the place of setting the env.

Answer (score 3):

Per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/globalization), you should set the environment variable to `1` to disable globalization. Like this

```
environment:
    - ConnectionStrings:Context=Server=MicroserviceTemplateDDD_Service1_database;Database=Database;User Id=pa;Password=P4ssW0rd!;
    - DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=1
```

Since you always need to set it to run your container, it'll be a good idea to put the configuration into the image. You can put it at the beginning of the dockerfile and remove it from the docker-compose file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=1
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

That way you can't forget to set it and have the error pop up again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Removing the DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=1 from the compose did not work for me. Now i get a FileNotFound Exception with my Appsettings... "The expected physical path was '/app/AppSettings.json'" seems like something wrong with my copy directiories. The appsettings.json is in the same path as my dockerfile

Comment: Linux is case sensitive, so if you try to load `AppSettings.json` (rather than the default `appsettings.json`), then your file also needs to be called `AppSettings.json`

Comment: still getting the error. is there a way to "inspect" the docker image to see the folder structure?

Comment: I postet the problem in a new question, maybe you know this answer too
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72545834/net-6-docker-appsettings-json-not-found

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and got around it by adding this condition in the csproj

```
  <ItemGroup Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('Windows'))">
    <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.AppLocalIcu" Value="68.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```